# How to control landscape and portrait programmatically in android?

Tags: android

I developed on application using android sdk 4.0 and I install that .apk file in my samsung tab.  When I run that application it is working properly.  If I change the tab portrait to landscape or in reverse the screen also changed.

But my requirement is irrespective of changing the mode either portrait to landscape to Landscape to portrait, my application should run in portrait mode only.

Answer (score 19):

add `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` for each activity in your manifest.xml file.

You can do this programmatically too, for all your activities making an `AbstractActivity` that all your activities extends.:-

```
public abstract class AbstractActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can define mode in AndroidManifest.xml as follows,

`android:screenOrientation="portrait"` after the `android:name=".activityName"`

for example like this,

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

and from activity class you can use following code,

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use this for landscape

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

To change to portrait mode, use the

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your manifest file,

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

Then add this to your java class:

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you search first, you'll find this question answered already.  I'll post the answer again here though.

Go to your manifest file, and under the activity that you want to keep portrait only, insert the following line
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
An example is given below.

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
      android:label="Your Activoity"
      android:screenOrientation="portrait">
```

this will make your activity forced to be in portrait mode only, even if you hold the device in landscape mode.