# How to made single apk on different mode for Tablet and Phone in Android?

Tags: android

I wanted to show different views on Tablet and Phones but I am not able to switch mode for device. Requirement for Tablet is Landscape mode and for Phone is in Potrait mode. What changes should I do in `AndroidManifest.xml` so that a single generated apk file meets my requirements ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use java code in your activity to do this

```
  if(isTabletDevice)
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
    else
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
```

**isTabletDevice code**

```
public static boolean isTabletDevice(Context activityContext) {
    // Verifies if the Generalized Size of the device is XLARGE to be
    // considered a Tablet
    boolean xlarge = ((activityContext.getResources().getConfiguration().screenLayout & 
                        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_MASK) == 
                        Configuration.SCREENLAYOUT_SIZE_XLARGE);

    // If XLarge, checks if the Generalized Density is at least MDPI
    // (160dpi)
    if (xlarge) {
        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        Activity activity = (Activity) activityContext;
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

        // MDPI=160, DEFAULT=160, DENSITY_HIGH=240, DENSITY_MEDIUM=160,
        // DENSITY_TV=213, DENSITY_XHIGH=320
        if (metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_DEFAULT
                || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH
                || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM
                || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_TV
                || metrics.densityDpi == DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH) {

            // Yes, this is a tablet!
            return true;
        }
    }

    // No, this is not a tablet!
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see the below line for your answer

[Determine if the device is a smartphone or tablet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9279111/determine-if-the-device-is-a-smartphone-or-tablet)

Find screen size dynamically and set screen mode landscape or portrait mode.

set programmatically  landscape or portrait mode.

[How to control landscape and portrait programmatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12968359/how-to-control-landscape-and-portrait-programmatically-in-android)